# Sticky nav bar making content jump

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky nav bar and I'm using twitter bootstrap. When ever I scroll past a certain point my sticky navbar is displayed, but when it's displayed my content jumps up. What I want is my content to stay where it is and not jump.

My HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="top_menu_wrapper">
    <div class="toggle_wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="main_menu_header">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button class="navbar-header collapsed move-navtoggle" 
                      data-target="#main-menu" data-toggle="collapse" 
                      type="button">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse main_menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav home-nav">
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">News & Events</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearboth"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>some content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

My JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 186) {
        $('.top_menu_wrapper').addClass('navbar-fixed-top').css({
            margin: '0 auto',
            width: '1024px',
            'border-top': '6px solid #6097dd'
        });
    } else {
        $('.top_menu_wrapper').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top').css({
            width: '100%',
            'border-top': 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

I tried making a jsfiddle but I'm not able to replicate my error. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxofn3xg/)

Comment: remove height from .home-nav

Comment: Can you explain your issue, your post is not understanding!

Comment: I suggest using bootstrap affix functionality. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix i think that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove height from `.home-nav`.  the height of `.home-nav` is small and the content of navigation is large.That bounce is coming because first full navigation is displayed and then the height is hiding contact us. which results in bounce.

```
.home-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I had to put another wrapper around my menu div and set that height to the same height as my menu. And it worked.